# GLSurfaceView: transparent background and overlay view on top of it

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need a **GLSurfaceView** with a **transparent background** (because I need to see a view  below it) and I have successfully created it with the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />


    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

From what I've understand, the only way to make the GLSurfaceView transparent is to adding **view.setZOrderOnTop(true)** to the GLSurfaceView. What follows is how I've declared the GLSurfaceView:

```
mGlSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true); //this is the line of code that is causing my problem
mGlSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
mGlSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
mGlSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
mGlSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
mGlSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
mGlSurfaceView.requestRender();
```

Now, with that ZOrderOnTop flag set to true, I can't no more see the ImageView that, in the xml, is after the GLSurfaceView.

**My question:** Does exists a way to place a view over a transparent GLSurfaceView ?

Comment: Got any solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't find any solution yet

Comment: I have the same issue!! Anything yet!!?